# Python Re, need a list of matches

Tags: python, regex

Say we have a string, `'123A......'`. I have a collection of other strings that also begin with `'123A......'` where after the A are other letters of the alphabet, for example, `'123AA.....'` and `'123AB.....'` and `'123ABA....'` and so on.

I want to make a dictionary where the key would be `'123A......'` and the value would be a list of the matches in the collection. I think doing this with regular expressions would be way better than some hodgepodge programmatic way...

So far I was thinking something like

```
baseMatch = re.compile('123A......')
baseMatch.findall('123A[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]')
```

But this looks lame and I have a suspicion that there is a better way.

Comment: It looks like You have tried to use regexp in both cases as regexp and as string where You are trying to find substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a quantifier in your regex, like so:

```
baseMatch = re.compile('123A[A-Z]{6}')
baseMatch.findall('123AABCDEFxyz123AAABCDExyz')
['123AABCDEF', '123AAABCDE']
```

Comment: Thank you, in the `[A-Z]`, how can I also make a `.` match as well? Would it be `[A-Z\.]`?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the prefixes (the keys), just do

```
dic = dict()
st = '123AHELLO'
val = st.split('123A')[1]
dic['123A'] = val
```

your question however is not clear. if you want to extract subcollection of suffixes when prefix is `'123A'` then you can do

```
st_lst = ['123AHELLO','123AHALLO','123BHELLO','123AGREAT']
res = [st.split('123A')[1] for st in st_lst if '123A' in st]
```

gives you

```
>>> res
['HELLO', 'HALLO', 'GREAT']
```

Comment: Much appreciated and I'll probably end up using this, but that in mind I wanted to use at least at little bit of regex.

Answer (score 0):

If your "key" is always the first 4 characters you could, again, split then dictionary a list. dicts offer very fast look ups which is a good method of indexing.

```
indx = dict()
inp = ['123AAAA','123ABBB','123ACCC']
for line in inp:
  try:
    indx[line[:4]].append(line[4:])
  except KeyError:
    indx[line[:4]] = []
    indx[line[:4]].append(line[4:])

>>indx['123A']
['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']
```

I'll probably get frowned on for using "try:" to initialize a dict() on the fly though :)